# JGoodies DefaultFormBuilder - add a row dynamically

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jgoodies

In my form there is a `JComboBox`, and depending on what is selected I would like to add some additional rows (labels and `JTextFields`) to the form just below the `JComboBox` and push the rest of the fields that many rows lower. Is this possible with JGoodies [`DefaultFormBuilder`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jgoodies/forms/1.2.0/forms-1.2.0-javadoc.jar!/com/jgoodies/forms/builder/DefaultFormBuilder.html) (or any other technique), and if so how?

Comment: Probably just using the builder to add more fields and calling `revalidate()` on the parent container should do it.

Comment: DefaultFormBuilder is a third party framework to create JPanel forms, and you can't just add more fields and call revalidate(). It does not work like this at all.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the JGoodies Forms library/framework? You cannot add a field and specify the row. It's not something that's even available in the API: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jgoodies/forms/1.2.0/forms-1.2.0-javadoc.jar!/index.html?com/jgoodies/forms/builder/DefaultFormBuilder.html

Comment: My bad, I missed the fact you wanted to **insert** as opposed to **append** components.  In that case, you might put an empty panel immediately after the combo. and add the new components into that.

Comment: Yes but doing that will leave a blank row when it's not needed. That doesn't shift the rows down, it just puts an empty row. And if there are multiple fields/rows, then this could be a lot of blank space.

Comment: Btw, if you're the one who downvoted this question, you may want to adjust your vote...

Comment: *"if you're the one who downvoted this question"*  Nope.  Don't know why it was down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no proper way. So what I ended up doing was creating a JPanel for each field with a BoderLayout. Then I added the max number of fields I would ever need to the form. Then when I needed to move fields down, I would remove them from the allocated JPanel's and push them to the ones below in a loop.

Not exactly the prettiest or most elegant but I couldn't find another solution at all...